# Trying to find the intersection of two polygons

Tags: javascript, polygon, intersection

I am looking for a code in JavaScript to find the intersection of two convex polygons. Suppose var poly1 = [ [x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],[x4,y4]] and var poly2 = [ [x5,y5],[x6,y6],[x7,y7],[x8,y8]], and want to find the intersection polygon returned by the array of coordinates similar to poly1 or poly2.

Comment: this is not a javascript question , ask in algorithms tag

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I found the following web site at which the code snippet for finding the intersection of two polygons are available in different programming languages.
http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Sutherland-Hodgman_polygon_clipping#JavaScript